# Heads/Tails 900 times, find k such that $P(k \leq T \leq 480) = 0.1$ with T the number of Tails

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Heads/Tails 900 times, find k such that $P(k \leq T \leq 480) = 0.1$ with T the number of Tails.
I will use the **CLT** because I know that $$P(z_{1} \leq \frac{S_{N} - \mu N}{\sqrt{N} \sigma} \leq z_{2})$$

We have $S_{900}$ a sum of Bernoulli($\frac{1}{2}$) so $\mu = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
But here I just don't know what to do.. Do you have any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start working a *similar* problem:

$T \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 900, p = 1/2),$ so start by showing that $E(T) = 450$ and $SD(T) = 15.$  Then
$$0.1 = P(k \le T \le 450) \approx P\left(\frac{k - 450}{15} \le \frac{T - E(T)}{SD(T)}
\le \frac{450 - 450}{15} \right) = P\left(\frac{k-450}{15} \le Z \le 0\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.

Using standard normal tables (backwards), you should be able to deduce the
value of $(k-450)/15$ and solve for $k.$ It may help to draw a sketch.

Of course, it is too much to expect
the the resulting $k$ will be exactly an integer, so 'round' appropriately.

The normal approximation should work
well enough to get an answer for $k$ that gives a probability very near
to the desired $0.1.$

You will be using standard normal and $\mathsf{Norm}(450, 15)$. Below are
sketches of both. The area *for my problem* is between the vertical red lines (on both
sketches). You should make one type of sketch for *your problem.*

[image]

Comment: What is SD comparing to my main equation in the center ?

Comment: $SD(T) = \sqrt{Np(1-p)} = 15.$ Your SD for a single Bernoulli trial should be $\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$ $= \sqrt{1/4} = 1/2.$ It may be easier to deal with the binomial random variable $T$ which is the sum of $n$ Bernoulli trials. // In working _your_ problem you may want to _start_ by finding $P(450 \le T \le 480).$ Then figure out what adjustment needs to be made for $k$ instead of $450.$